# Problems while compiling libgphoto2

Tags: compilation, libgphoto2

I am trying to get the latest version of libgphoto2 (2.5.12) and gphoto2 (2.5.11) to work on Debian Jessie. I downloaded and extracted the source files from git and followed the install instructions:

```
autoreconf --install --symlink
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

Configure worked without any major issues. The only thing I noticed is that it mentions "libusb-1.0 no" but "libusb yes". I tried reinstalling libusb-1.0-0(-dev), but no change.

The following is an excerpt of the make output:

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/max/Downloads/libgphoto2-2.5.12/libgphoto2_port'
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -module -no-undefined -avoid-version -export-dynamic -export-symbols ./iolib.sym -rpath '/usr/local/lib/libgphoto2_port/0.12.0'  -o usb1.la  libusb1/usb1_la-libusb1.lo ./libgphoto2_port/libgphoto2_port.la -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0   -lpthread 
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/usb1.ver
libtool: link: echo "{ global:" > .libs/usb1.ver
libtool: link:  cat ./iolib.sym | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1;/" >> .libs/usb1.ver
libtool: link:  echo "local: *; };" >> .libs/usb1.ver
libtool: link:  gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  libusb1/.libs/usb1_la-libusb1.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/max/Downloads/libgphoto2-2.5.12/libgphoto2_port/libgphoto2_port/.libs ./libgphoto2_port/.libs/libgphoto2_port.so -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so -ldl -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a -ludev -lpthread  -g -O2   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,usb1.so -Wl,-version-script -Wl,.libs/usb1.ver -o .libs/usb1.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a(libusb_1_0_la-core.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:820: recipe for target 'usb1.la' failed
make[4]: *** [usb1.la] Error 1
```

...and make stops. I simply don't know what to do as "-fPIC" is mentioned in the gcc options.

If I can give you further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by manually compiling and installing a new version of libusb1. Download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/?source=typ_redirect), then just configure, make and install as described in the instructions. At least for me it worked.